# Facebook Graph API name field is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm seeing the error `name field is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher` from Facebook, this just started occurring a few days ago:

```
{taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - Graph API error 400 
    
    {"error":{"message":"(#12) name field is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12,"fbtrace_id":"AyLdQkfLTBKjUwQ5dURy-Lf"}}
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
        result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
      File "/usr/local/airflow/repo/plugins/facebook_plugin/facebook_operators.py", line 88, in execute
        response = self.fbhook.get_post_insights(page_id, page_token, post_date)
      File "/usr/local/airflow/repo/plugins/facebook_plugin/facebook_hooks.py", line 89, in get_post_insights
    
        f"Graph API error {response.status_code} {response.url}"
    Exception: Graph API error 400  
    {"error":{"message":"(#12) name field is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12,"fbtrace_id":"AyLdQkfLTBKjUwQ5dURy-Lf"}}
```

I'm trying to get more information on 'name' and what this field has been replaced with, where can I find that?

Comment: What node are you calling? Have you checked the dev docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has officially depreciated Graph Api 3.2 on May 4th, 2021, and will move your app on Graph API version 3.3.

They have depreciated many of the fields and have provided alternative fields to keep using the Facebook data. In your case {name} has been changed to attachments{title}.

Please see the below URL to find more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.3/